# An online hosted wiki-type collaboration software with effective mobile access

Tags: note-taking, collaboration, wiki

I'm trying to find an option that will allow a small team of us - two to three people - to work collaboratively on assembling a lot of information regarding the medical condition of a friend of ours.

Since there are a lot of small notes the easiest way to do this seems to be a wiki-style system that'll let us link between notes.  The others are not very tech-savvy so if possible I'd like to avoid having them install an app, and also that the service be quite lightweight.

I'm quite surprised to find that there is no service that seems to be able to provide this:

- [Slimwiki](http://www.slimwiki.com) opens well on mobile browsers but adding a link is a pain within a mobile browser and there are frequent bugs (e.g. try cutting and pasting text from inside one cell of a table to another and you get an undelete-able mess).
- [Dropbox Paper](http://paper.dropbox.com) has an Android mobile app that [doesn't allow you to add hyperlinks](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-Paper/How-do-I-add-a-hyperlink-in-the-android-app/td-p/275232) (huh???) and doesn't let you edit a note from a mobile except through the app (it won't let you edit it from a browser).
- [Notejoy](http://www.notejoy.com) has no Android app and trying to edit from an Android mobile browser - I've tried Firefox, Chrome and Opera Touch - is a frustrating experience, especially with links.  Also  no easy way to link to another note (you have to [get the URL of that note and link to it instead](https://notejoy.com/help/how-do-i-link-between-notes)).
- [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) seems too heavyweight for our old computers (and probably our phones, haven't tried) and doesn't lend itself to easy wiki style interlinking.
- [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) might possibly be good - haven't really tried it - but it seems expensive and this ideally needs to be free.
- Wikispaces has closed down.
- [PBWorks](http://www.pbworks.com) also seems to have no mobile app and the website is very mobile unfriendly.

I'm surprised at this - the functionality we're looking for seems to be what most of these claim to be providing, but all of them fall down in one crucial respect or another.  Can someone please help?? :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found the solution to this problem - [Nuclino](http://www.nuclino.com).  It does not have a mobile app, but the website is very fast and responsive in Android.  Adding links is still a problem - but this is more [about Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195638/cannot-edit-a-link-field-in-a-website-like-nuclino-notejoy-slimwiki-etc-in) than about Nuclino - and unlike the other options, it lets you use markdown formatting, so adding a link when editing from mobile is as simple as adding a link here.  The markdown tools make entering information on the computer a pleasure as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should also take a look at [Slite](http://slite.com): desktop and mobile app. It lets your team share and write notes together + it's a great way to store wiki-style internal documentation.

Seems like it answers all your criteria:
- Mobile editing + note linking 
- Very user friendly